# C++ - Behaviour of derived class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm preparing my exam. Below is output of a sample question, the block 3 confuses me.

```
--- Block 1 ---
H
SM
2 x S
DP
--- Block 2 ---
H
SM
2 x S
DP
--- Block 3 ---
H
Copy SM
1 x S
Copy DP
--- Block 4 ---
H=
--- Block 5 ---
 ̃H
--- Block 6 ---
 ̃DP
 ̃S
 ̃SM
 ̃H
 ̃DP
 ̃S
 ̃SM
 ̃H
```

We pass a `Deadpool` type object to construct a new `Deadpool` object, so copy constructor(ctor) should be called. `Deadpool` copy ctor should call `Spiderman` copy ctor, because of inheritance. Then, `Spiderman` copy ctor calls `Hero` ctor for same reason, so why is there `1 x S`? Who called the `Sword` constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Weapon { };

class Sword : public Weapon {
public:
    Sword(int n = 1) { cout << n << " x S" << endl; }
    ~Sword() { cout << " ̃S" << endl; }
};

class Hero {
    Weapon* w;
public:
    Hero() { cout << "H" << endl; w = new Weapon; }
   ~Hero() { cout << " ̃H" << endl; delete w; }
    virtual const Hero& operator=(const Hero& h) { cout << "H=" << endl; return *this;}
};

class SpiderMan : public Hero {
    Weapon* w;
public:
    SpiderMan() { cout << "SM" << endl; w = new Weapon; }
    SpiderMan(const SpiderMan& s) { cout << "Copy SM" << endl; w = new Weapon; }
    virtual ~SpiderMan() { cout << " ̃SM" << endl; delete w; }
    const SpiderMan& operator=(const SpiderMan& s) { cout << "SM=" << endl; return *this;}
};

class DeadPool : public SpiderMan {
    Sword sword;
public:
    DeadPool() : sword(2) { cout << "DP" << endl; }
    DeadPool(const DeadPool& d) : SpiderMan(d) { cout << "Copy DP" << endl; }
    ~DeadPool() { cout << " ̃DP" << endl; }
    const DeadPool& operator=(const DeadPool& d) { cout << "DP=" << endl; return *this;}
};

int main() {
    cout << "--- Block 1 ---" << endl;
    Hero* hero = new DeadPool;
    cout << "--- Block 2 ---" << endl;
    SpiderMan* spiderman = new DeadPool;
    cout << "--- Block 3 ---" << endl;
    DeadPool deadpool(*dynamic_cast<DeadPool*>(spiderman));
    cout << "---        Block 4 ---" << endl;
    *hero = *spiderman;
    cout << "--- Block 5 ---" << endl;
    delete hero;
    cout << "--- Block 6 ---" << endl;
    delete spiderman;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who called the `Sword` constructor?

`DeadPool` has a data member `sword` with type `Sword`, it's not mentioned in the copy constructor of `DeadPool`, then it'll be initialized by its default constructor. That's why you got the output `1 x S`, between the invocation of the constructor of base `SpiderMan` and invocation of the constructor of `DeadPool`.